# How to Log In To ROS Answers with Google

Tags: ros, meta, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I normally sign in to ros.answers with my google login. But it looks as though something has changed, because the icon is different now and it says  "Click to see if your google login still works for ROS Answers." Mine doesn't, it would seem. What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207951/how-to-log-in-to-ros-answers-with-google/) by [DLu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22279/dlu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Google Discontinued OpenID 2.0 support last week. [details from google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable)

We have had to switch to use the Google+ login system. It works just like the old one, but it's not connected. We're trying to connect

If you were using google to log in. You will need to log in via password (use the email based password reset if you've never set your password or forgot it) and then you can add Google+ as a login provider form your profile settings.

We are attempting to associate the new and old accounts via matching emails, but it's does not seem to work well.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like there's a ticket for this, but it hasn't been fixed yet: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/109

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1